# How to create executable jar with dependency jars both inside and outside of the jar (intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a wee problem with building my project into an executable jar. I'm using about 20 different external libraries in my project but one of the libraries is a provider (bcprov-jdk15on.jar). I can successfully extract all the other libraries in my project jar so that the result is a single jar. However, when I'm trying to extract the provider library then the process will break (remove) the signature on the library and JVM gives me a JNI error. Because of that I'd like to create a jar that includes the 19 other libraries in the final jar and then the bcprov-jdk15on.jar in /lib folder next to the executable. So that the hierarchy would look something like this:

```
myproject.jar  
lib  
 |_bcprov-jdk15on.jar
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 and the the Artifact options don't seem to provide this specific functionality. I can create a jar that has either all the libraries in a /lib folder next to the jar or all the libraries extracted in the jar but I can't seem to make the in-between solution work. I can define the wanted structure when I'm building an artifact of type "Other" but then I cannot define the main class for this artifact, which means that I'm not able to run this from the terminal. Is it even possible to build this kind of artifact using the UI or do I have to make some kind of maven or ant build for that? Some insight into how this could be achieve would be very helpful. If there is something crucial I left unmentioned here, feel free to ask for more details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look about Maven Shade plugin if you can use Maven. By using it with a good configuration, the "package" command will create a shaded.jar containning all the libs/dependencies if needed.

Comment: I can use Maven for sure but right now I'm wondering if IntelliJ provides some kind of built in functionality for that purpose. If somebody can say that this is definitely not possible with IntelliJ and I absolutely have to use some plugin for this specific purpose then of course I have no other option.